# Symfony 2.5 - I am unable to catch PDOException

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, exception

I am in the final phase of building a new project based on symfony 2.5 and I thought that it would be nice to have custom error pages. I created my own Exception Listener, see the code below:

**Here is the service declaration:**

```
kernel.listener.core_exception_listener:
    class: MyCompany\CoreBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: [@templating, @kernel]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

**Here is the actual PHP class:**

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\CoreBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    protected $templating;
    protected $kernel;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, $kernel)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // provide the better way to display a enhanced error page only in prod environment, if you want
        if ('prod' == $this->kernel->getEnvironment()) {
            // exception object
            $exception = $event->getException();

            // new Response object
            $response = new Response();

            if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
                $template = 'CoreBundle:Exception:404.html.php';
            } else {
                $template = 'CoreBundle:Exception:exception.html.php';
            }

            $response->setContent(
                // create you custom template AcmeFooBundle:Exception:exception.html.twig
                $this->templating->render(
                    $template,
                    array('exception' => $exception)
                )
            );


            // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception
            // that holds status code and header details
            if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
                $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
                $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
            } else {
                $response->setStatusCode(500);
            }

            // set the new $response object to the $event
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfect with 404 pages but unfortunately it does not work with PDOExceptions. As an example, I stopped my mysql server and refreshed the page, instead of my custom error page I actually get the exception trace log and a HTTP response code 200 ( like wtf.. :) )

Any advices?
Thanks

P.S.: creating the file app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig has absolutely no effect..

P.P.S.: Adding priority property to the service declaration has no effect also.

Answer (score 2):

To catch a `PDOException`, you have to namespace it.
Either add it as a use statement or add the leading \ when it is called.
For example;

```
try {
   // your code
} catch (\PDOException $pdo_ex) {
   die("Oops, ".$pdo_ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: the exception is thrown at runtime by doctrine - my test included the scenario when the mysql server is unavailable. I am unable to insert the try catch code block because that would mean that I'd have to change the code core.

Answer (score 2):

*This is code help me with Expections errors by http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/nm7o/catching-orm-dbal-and-pdo-exceptions-in-symfony*

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    try {
        $em->persist($country);
        $em->flush();
        $message = 'Done';
    } catch (DBALException $e) {
        $message = sprintf('DBALException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $message = sprintf('PDOException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    } catch (ORMException $e) {
        $message = sprintf('ORMException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = sprintf('Exception [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    }

    echo $message;
}
```

}